# Its possible use outputDirectory two times in my pom.xml?

Tags: maven, plugins, maven-plugin

I have one problem in my java project. Basicaly, I want build and compile my project to export jar file in two distinct directories. It's possible? Because method I am using is not working in my pom.xml

**I was trying to use this code below, but always in the second outputDirectory, it didn't work.**

```xml
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-resources</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>C:\My\First\Directory\Folder</outputDirectory>
                            <outputDirectory>C:\My\Second\Directory\Folder</outputDirectory>
                            <resources>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>C:\Local\Of\My\Jar\</directory>
                                    <filtering>false</filtering>
                                    <includes>
                                        <include>myJar.jar</include>
                                    </includes>
                                </resource>
                            </resources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
     </build>
```

Comment: Why should it go to two distinct directories?

Comment: I need build it in two distinct directories for me to save time in my compilations

Comment: That sounds strange. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I want to copy my compiled jar to two separate folders.

Comment: That is what you already said in the question. How exactly do you think you can save time by copying to two folders? Note that people are usually not doing this, and that there is probably a better, well-established way to solve your compilation speed problem.

Comment: You got me wrong. I just want to copy a jar to two folders, not to save compile time, but to save time copying the jar file to another folder.

Comment: Yes, but why on earth does it save you time? Could you please describe in more detail what you are trying to do? If you just need the JAR in the compilation of a different project, then there are much easier approaches.

Comment: In this case, I need to copy the jar file of a project to two different folders on my computer.

Comment: Nathan, I am trying to help you. But I can only help you if you say WHY you want to do what you are trying to do and describe the underlying problem. You always repeat that you need to copy the JAR to two folders, but I think that you probably just did not know a better solution. What is the reason you need the JAR in two folders? Please do not just answer in one sentence, but describe it more detail.

Comment: Mr Meier, I'm sorry for my english. I'm brazilian, so maybe I made a mistake in typing what I need. So, I am trying to copy a JAR file from a project folder to two others directories. For this, i am using "maven-resources-plugin", to do this function. Meanwhile, when I compile, it only copies the JAR file into 1 folder (that I defined in the outputDirectory), but into the other folder, it doesn't copy it. I'm trying discover possibles solutions for this problem. Can you help me?

Comment: So what is the purpose of copying the JAR to the second folder? Why do you need it there? Do you need it there to add it to a different project? Or to run it? Or for what other reason? You probably did not wake up and say "I need to copy a JAR to two folders", but you probably had some kind of problem and then you thought "copying to two folders might be the solution". What was this problem? (And let me repeat: You cannot copy to two folders and you probably don't need to anyway. But you need to help me unterstand where your "copying to two folders" came from)

Comment: The purpose of copying this JAR into two folders, is to automate the process. Currently, since it only copies to one of the folders, I am having to manually copy the file and paste it into the other one. That is why I would like maven itself to do this function for me.

Comment: You probably do not need it in the second folder. But I can only tell you how to do it properly, if you tell me why it should be in the second folder.

Comment: I am working with two modules within my single java project. I have made a method to compile these two modules so that they auto-complete, but there are two executors for each. These executors are in two different folders. This is why I need to compile it twice, and in two folders.

Comment: If you use a multi-module maven project, you can have two modules in one project and compile everything automatically, without copying or compiling twice.

Answer (score 0):

You can only copy to one directory.

But I never heard that somebody needed to copy to a second directory.

So you probably won't need it.